# Product between two data.frames columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frames:

The first one is the coefficients of my regressions for each day:

```
> parametrosBase
               beta0          beta1         beta4
2015-12-15 0.1622824 -0.012956819 -0.04637442
2015-12-16 0.1641884 -0.007914548 -0.06170213
2015-12-17 0.1623660 -0.005618474 -0.05914809
2015-12-18 0.1643263  0.005380472 -0.08533237
2015-12-21 0.1667710  0.003824588 -0.09040071
```

The second one is: the independent (x) variables:

```
    > head(ir_dfSTORED)
         ind   m h0x       h1x       h4x beta0_h0x beta1_h1x beta4_h4x
1 2015-12-15  21   1 0.5642792 0.2859359         0         0         0
2 2015-12-15  42   1 0.3606713 0.2831963         0         0         0
3 2015-12-15  63   1 0.2550200 0.2334554         0         0         0
4 2015-12-15  84   1 0.1943071 0.1883048         0         0         0
5 2015-12-15 105   1 0.1561231 0.1544524         0         0         0
6 2015-12-15 126   1 0.1302597 0.1297947         0         0         0
> tail(ir_dfSTORED)
           ind    m h0x         h1x         h4x beta0_h0x beta1_h1x beta4_h4x
835 2015-12-21 2415   1 0.006799321 0.006799321         0         0         0
836 2015-12-21 2436   1 0.006740707 0.006740707         0         0         0
837 2015-12-21 2457   1 0.006683094 0.006683094         0         0         0
838 2015-12-21 2478   1 0.006626457 0.006626457         0         0         0
839 2015-12-21 2499   1 0.006570773 0.006570773         0         0         0
840 2015-12-21 2520   1 0.006516016 0.006516016         0         0         0
```

What i want is to multiply the beta0 column of `"parametrosBase"` by h0x column of `"ir_dfSTORED"` and store the result in the beta0_h0x column. And the same for the others: beta1 and beta4

The problem im facing is with the dates in "ind" column. This multiplication has to respect the dates.

So, once i change the day in `"ir_dfSTORED"` i have to change to the same day in `"parametrosBase"`.

For example:

The first rowof `"parametrosBase"` df is

`2015-12-15 0.1622824 -0.012956819 -0.04637442`

is fixed for the `2015-12-15` day. And then i do the product. Once i enter on the `2015-12-16` day i will have to consider the second row of `"parametrosBase"` df.

How can i do this?

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should merge the two datasets first:

```
parametrosBase$ind <- rownames(parametrosBase)
df <- merge(ir_dfSTORED,parametrosBase)
df <- within(df,{
  beta0_h0x <- beta0*h0x
  beta1_h0x <- beta1*h0x
  beta4_h0x <- beta4*h0x
})
```

Since I don't know the structure of the data, you may have to convert the dates from `rownames` to a date format in order for the merge to work.  Using `ind` as the name of the date in `parametrosBase` is key to making `merge` work, otherwise you'll have to specify the variables to merge by.